# Кнопка с двумя строками внутри

Tags: html

Подскажите, как сделать `submit`, чтобы текст в ней располагался в две строки. Просто короче текста для кнопки не придумаешь, а получается она чересчур длинная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Текст кнопки - это не строка, которую можно форматировать, а значение этой кнопки. Можно сделать имитацию кнопки **submit**, но уже с использованием JS,jQuery etc. Например так:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="my_form">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="some_key" value />
    </p>
    <div id="my_submit">Моя собственная кнопка!<br />Отправить запрос</div>
</form>
```

**CSS** (здесь сделаете вид кнопки, какой хотите)

```
#my_submit {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#my_submit').click(function(){
    $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: очень хороший вариант, так я их подгоню под те кнопки, что есть на форме. Только вот вопрос (я ток начинаю программировать на веб) куда выот jQuery пихать, чтоб событие срабатывало?

Comment: все нашла, где div добавила Onclick="..."

Comment: А если у посетителя выключен javascript? :]

Answer (score 6):

Может быть, тег button решит вопрос?

```
<button>Очень длинный текст<br />из двух строчек</button>
```

Comment: да он решил. вот только жаль отличается сильно от других кнопок. ну да что поделать, придумаю что-нибудь

Comment: Чтобы меньше отличался, css примените.